# Can I make a WiFi extender/access point from my raspberry pi 3b+ using WiFi only

Tags: raspbian

How can I make a WiFi extender/access point using wifi only, I do not have Ethernet but do have a WiFi dongle to use. Note: I do not have Ethernet for my pi. If there is a solution please tell me how I can do this.

Comment: This question is to broad.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a wifi repeater that creates an access point and simultaneously connect as client to another remote access point. You can do it with the on-board wifi device without needing a second wifi dongle because it supports both modes at the same time. How to setup it you can look at [Access point as WiFi repeater, optional with bridge](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/89804/79866).

But if you like to use your additional USB/WiFi dongle you can look at [Access point as WiFi router/repeater with additional WiFi-dongle](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/95073/79866). It makes things easier.