# How to setup an acces point on 8812au driver using systemd networking?

Tags: networking, wifi, systemd

I've been using [this guide](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/95072/access-point-as-wifi-repeater-with-additional-wifi-dongle/95303?noredirect=1#comment154980_95303)

I've setup a Raspberry Pi 3+ which has a WiFi dongle and onboard WiFi to do this. The WiFi dongle is an AC600 with the 8812au chipset, requiring compiled kernel drivers, which I compiled installed. This is my wlan0, the onboard chipset is wlan1.

When I follow your guide and use the onboard as the AP, everything works fine. However, when I switch them around, and try to use wlan0 as my AP (which is the intention), then the access point doesn't get setup. When I inspect the journal I find:

```
Mar 13 15:53:14 HTL wpa_supplicant[260]: nl80211: Could not configure driver mode
Mar 13 15:53:14 HTL wpa_supplicant[260]: nl80211: deinit ifname=wlan0 disabled_11b_rates=0
```

It seems wpa_supplicant is trying to load the nl80211 driver instead of the 8812au driver?

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

One time you are switching the interfaces **wlan0** and **wlan1** and another time when referencing the instructions behind the link you have given, it is unclear if you also switch them. Raspbian always uses **wlan0** for its on-board wifi chip by default. To not get confused please let us use **wlan0** for the on-board wifi chip and **wlan1** for your USB/wifi dongle, no matter what is used for an access point and for the client connection. It also fits to the naming of the physical devices **phy0** and **phy1**. Following this you want to use **wlan1** as access point but it doesn't work.

Using **wlan0** as access point is working. It is unclear if the uplink client connection with **wlan1** is also working in this case. Please ensure that it will do. Using the USB/wifi dongle for the client connection should be less error prone so you can better check if the compiled driver is working. If it is running then in the next step you can switch the usage of **wlan0** and **wlan1**.

To get some useful information please load the compiled driver for **8812au** and execute:

```
rpi ~$ iw phy phy1 info
```

You will get a bunch of information. Please only look at the sections `Supported interface modes:`, `Supported commands:` and `valid interface combinations:`. Please edit your question and paste them into it.