# No internet on client device when connected to Raspberry Pi

Tags: pi-3, access-point

I've been trying to set up RPi to act as both a wireless AP and wifi station simultaneously. I've got nothing but errors and bugs so far. I did however find this guide that creates a virtual AP and runs a station on the same card which im okay with (instead of using 2 seperate wifi cards)

Link to guide: https://imti.co/iot-wifi/

I followed the steps and everything seems to connect, the only problem is I am not receiving an internet connection on the device that connects to the AP of the RPi. I have made sure that the Pi does have acces to internet when its connected to the external network. The aim of my project is to connect the user to the internet through it to the outside network.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Ah, let me see.  So you have followed the IMTI's instructions and find everything OK (using only one wifi card).  The problem arises only when you start using 2 separate wifi cards. I have two questions: (1) Does IMIT allow you to use 2 wifi cards? (2) If IMIT does not say if two cards are allowed.  Did you make any changes to the IMTI's instructions to cater for two cards?

Comment: Any question which boils down to "I followed a tutorial and it doesn't work"  means either you didn't follow the tutorial or it doesn't work.

Comment: @user105104, I browsed IMIT's documents and found them very impressive.  I have no experience in the Docker thing.  I am going to learn it, and only afterwards I can be confident to try to reproduce your situation.  There are other things you may like to let us know, say what is your stretch version? wifi card spec?

Comment: There seems some confusion.  I thought I saw your answer but no longer found it.  You seemed to have mentioned two network cards and I commented, but all disappeared. Anyway, I tried again.  I do sometimes use two "network cards".  Actually one is the wift controller built into Rpi3.  Another card is actually a USB wifi dongle inserted into the Rpi's USB socket.  If I remember correctly, Raspbian will automatically switch to the USB wifi dongle.  In other words, you CANNOT use two "network cards" (one built in, the other USB Wifi dongle) at the same time. But I am still a newbiei, so not sure.

Comment: @tlfong01, yeah the comments seem to be removed.
I don't mind using only one WiFi card. My main problem is that I am not getting internet access on any device I cannot with to the raspberry pi

Comment: What do you mean with "dual network card" to be used with a Raspberry Pi 3? It has a built-in wifi chip and for a second wifi interface you need an USB/wifi dongle. Is it this what you mean?. You can comment your own question. Please address me with @Ingo, otherwise I won't see your reply.

Comment: @Zeyad Tarek, I see, so your two network card is a side problem.  Your main problem in on the AP part, everything else is OK as the IMTI instructions say.  So problem is not yet solved.  In this case, I am not going to close the file, but do some study on the newbie scary "Docker" thing (might take a long while! :)", then come back to reproduce you experiment (except not using NOOBS to start with.

Comment: @user105104, I have completed a rush course in things related to the project (Docker, Go etc). I need to refresh my memory on WiFi station, AP, and IOT, then I should have confidence to try to start reproducing your setup, perhaps tomorrow.

Comment: Little Birds just told me that Rpi4 is out.  So I will stall my IOT WiFi project for a while. (new features = dual display, 4K support, USB 3.0, real gigabit ethernet, Bluetooth 5.0 and more, ...)

Comment: I found this link that seems to fix the routing problem I had (no internet on use device thats connected to AP)

There is still a DNS problem in the docker though and I'm still not getting internet but at least the traffic is being routed properly
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44177580/routing-from-eth0-to-eth1-on-raspberry-with-jessie-lite-doesnt-work

Comment: @Ingo Yeah thats what I meant. Although I've discarded that idea because it turns out the external dongle I had was malfunctioning and I resorted to using the IoT-WiFi docker. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: @user105104, I am glad to hear that you found the problem with the second WiFi dongle, and that your found traffic routed OK. So as you said, there are still two problems, (1) no internet access, (2) DNS problem.  The WiFi newbie, ie, me, is going very slowly, and need a long while to catch up.  As I said, Rpi4 is coming out.  So I might take a break and see if I should switch this IOT Wifi station/AP config API project to Rpi4.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access point as WiFi router/repeater, optional with bridge](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/89803/access-point-as-wifi-router-repeater-optional-with-bridge) or [Access point as WiFi router/repeater with additional WiFi-dongle](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/95073/79866).

Comment: @user105104, already ordered 2 Pi4's (Argon40). hope to get toys soon (they say “in stock”)). I still need more time to learn WiFi, clarifying things, like repeater, bridge, IOT WiFi, JON config files.  I have little idea of the project you are doing - Station + AP, and using API.  BTW, are you going to use the CJ's API to build a website of IOT Wifii config?  All these seem a bit scary to a newbie like me.  So don't expect me to make any progress soon.  Cheers.

Comment: @user105104, I found the following post by #ingo Access point as WiFi router/repeater, optional with bridge
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/89803/access-point-as-wifi-router-repeater-optional-with-bridge  It is a bit over whelming for a newbie like me.  Do you think it is OK for newbie to start learning, or if it is good for your project?

Comment: @user105104, Now I am following the cjimti instructions to "Run The IOT Wifi Docker Container", using the following command: "$ docker run --rm --privileged --net host \
      -v $(pwd)/wificfg.json:/cfg/wificfg.json \
      cjimti/iotwifi"  Now I have a problem.  I don't  know the "<HOST_PATH>" and <CONTAINER_PATH>.  Do you have any "paths" for me to copy and paste?

Comment: @tlfong01, did you download the json config file? I didn't encounter this error before so I cant help you :/

Comment: @user105104, Ah yes, I followed the instructions and download everything, including the JSON config file.  I think my problem is that I don't know where are the "paths".  I guess this is no problem for regular linux guys, because they know all the defaults.  A newbie like me, needs to do some searching first.  Any way, I found the "docker" thing interesting.  But as I said, I am preparing for upgrading all my projects from Pi3 to Pi4, so I think it is god time for me to stall this IoT Wifi experiment now, and come back later, when I know more basic stuff. Good Luck and Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

***Question***

> Rpi3B+ Stretch9 WiFi Station + AP IOT Hotspot Docker Setting Up Problem

***Short Answer***

*1. WiFi Station + AP IOT Hotspot Based Config API Setup Notes V1.0*

> Now I am doing the first step of setting up - Installing the docker. 
>   This setup step is summarized in Appendix H below.

***Update 2019jun25hkt2104***

*Docker Hello World running OK, though I don't know what is going on.  Need to google again before moving on.*

[image: iot wifi]

*/ to continue, ...*

***Long Answer***

*Introduction*

> The OP's setup involving docker is a bit complicated.  I need to do
>   much research before I can duplicate his setup and tried to find the
>   problem.
>
> I have heard about the Docker thing for some time, but I have never
>   tried it.  Just now I skimmed the wikipedia and guess that it is sort
>   light weight and therefore space/time/process efficient virtual
>   machine thing like the very old guy System 360 VM.  Microsoft also has
>   similar light virtualization stuff.  Perhaps I start learning by doing, sort of MIT style ...

*One thing I don't understand is why the Wifi called "IOT WiFi".  Anyway, I think I can start messing around without understanding everything.  I am a huge fan of Oliver Heaviside. I always remember him saying the following:*

> Am I to refuse to eat because I do not fully understand the mechanism
>   of digestion? - Heaviside

*Research Notes*

*Engineering Experimentation Notes*

***References***

1. [Rpi3 WiFi Station + AP IOT hotspot based configuration API – Craig Johnston 2018mar15](https://imti.co/iot-wifi/)
2. [About Craig Johnston](https://imti.co/about/)
3. [Rpi3 As Wireless Client And Wireless AP – Raspberry Pi forum thread](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=36&t=138730&start=25)
4. [Tutorial on Setting up a Raspberry Pi as a WiFi access point – Adafruit](https://learn.adafruit.com/setting-up-a-raspberry-pi-as-a-wifi-access-point/install-software)
5. [How to connect to a WPA/WPA2 WiFi network using Linux command line – linuxcommando](https://linuxcommando.blogspot.com/2013/10/how-to-connect-to-wpawpa2-wifi-network.html)
6. [Automatically connect a Raspberry Pi to a Wifi network – weWorkWePlay](https://weworkweplay.com/play/automatically-connect-a-raspberry-pi-to-a-wifi-network/)
7. [Docker - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_(software))
8. [Go - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_(programming_language))
9. [Virtualisation – Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS-level_virtualisation)
10. [WAP (Wireless Access Point) - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_access_point)
11. [Hotspot (Wi-Fi) - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotspot_(Wi-Fi))

[12. Setting up a Raspberry Pi as an access point in a standalone network (NAT) - Rpi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md)

[13. cjimti iotwifi giihub](https://github.com/cjimti/iotwifi)

[14. No Internet on AP - zeyadtarek 2019jun23](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=243294)

[15. Wireless repeater - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_repeater)

[16. Wireless (Network) Bridge - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridging_(networking))

[17. Access point as WiFi router/repeater, optional with bridge](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/89803/access-point-as-wifi-router-repeater-optional-with-bridge)

***Appendices***

*Appendix A - WiFi Station + AP IOT HotsSpot (Craig Johnston) Learning Notes*

> ***IOT Wifi*** is very small/***8MB Docker Container*** built for the
>   Raspberry Pi 3. IOT Wifi exposes a simple ***JSON based REST API for
>   controlling the wireless network interface***. This container allows
>   the Raspberry Pi to accept wifi connections as an ***access point (aka
>   AP)*** while at the same time connecting to an existing ***wifi
>   network (station mode)***.
>
> ***Go*** (Golang) was used to develop the main application code, to produce
>   a minimal docker image with great performance. The container runs
>   Alpine Linux with small, optimized versions of ***hostapd,
>   wpa_supplicant and dnsmasq***, controlled by the container’s API
>   endpoints.

*Appendix B - Docker - Wikipedia Learning Notes*

> Docker is a set of coupled software-as-a-service and
>   platform-as-a-service products that use operating-system-level
>   ***virtualization*** to develop and deliver software in packages called ***containers***. The software that hosts the containers is
>   called ***Docker Engine***.
>
> Containers are isolated from each other and bundle their own software,
>   libraries and configuration files; they can communicate with each
>   other through well-defined channels. All containers are run by a
>   single operating-system kernel and are thus ***more lightweight than
>   virtual machines***. Containers are created from images that specify
>   their precise contents.

*Appendix C - Virtualization - Wikipedia Learning Notes*

> OS-level virtualization refers to an operating system paradigm in
>   which the kernel allows the existence of ***multiple isolated
>   user-space instances***. Such instances, called ***containers*** ... 
>   *may look like real computers from the point of view of programs running in them*. A computer program running on an ordinary operating
>   system can see all resources (connected devices, files and folders,
>   network shares, CPU power, quantifiable hardware capabilities) of that
>   computer. *However, programs running inside of a container can only
>   see the container's contents and devices assigned to the container.*
>
> On ordinary operating systems for personal computers [tlfong01 - Rpi
>   included?], a computer program can see (even though it might not be
>   able to access) all the system's resources. They include:
>
> Hardware capabilities, such as the CPU and the network connection Data
>   that can be read or written, such as files, folders and network shares
>   Connected peripherals it can interact with, such as webcam, printer,
>   scanner, or fax
>
> With operating-system-virtualization, or containerization, it is
>   possible to run programs within containers, to which only parts of
>   these resources are allocated.

*Appendix D - Go Wikipedia Learning Notes*

> Go, also known as Golang, is a ***statically typed, compiled***
>   programming language designed at Google. Go is syntactically similar
>   to C, but with memory safety, garbage collection, structural typing,
>   and ***CSP-style concurrency***.
>
> Go was designed at Google in 2007 to improve programming productivity
>   in an era of ***multicore, networked machines*** and large codebases.
>   The designers wanted to address criticism of other languages in use at
>   Google, but keep their useful characteristics:
>
> Static typing and run-time efficiency (like C++)
>
> ***Readability and usability (like Python or JavaScript)***
>
> High-performance ***networking and multiprocessing***
>
> The designers were primarily motivated by their shared dislike of C++.
>
> Go is influenced by C
>
> Distinctive approaches to particular problems:
>
> Built-in concurrency primitives: light-weight processes, channels, and
>   the select statement.
>
> An interface system in place of virtual inheritance, and type
>   embedding instead of non-virtual inheritance.
>
> A desire to keep the language specification ***simple enough to hold
>   in a programmer's head***, in part by omitting features which are
>   common in similar languages.
>
> Go's syntax includes changes from C aimed at keeping code concise and
>   readable.
>
> Go has a number of built-in types, ... Record types can be defined
>   with the struct keyword.
>
> ***Pointers*** are available for all types,
>
> For a pair of types K, V, the type map[K]V is the type of ***hash
>   tables mapping*** are built into the language
>
> Go provides two features that replace class inheritance:
>   ***embedding***, which can be viewed as an automated form of composition or delegation, ***interfaces***, which provides runtime
>   polymorphism.
>
> In Go's package system, each package has a path and a name
>
> The Go language has built-in facilities, as well as library support,
>   for writing concurrent programs. ***Concurrency refers not only to CPU
>   parallelism, but also to asynchrony***: letting slow operations like a
>   database or network-read run while the program does other work, as is
>   common in event-based servers.
>
> Go's concurrency can be used to program ***shared memory
>   multi-processor machines***.

Appendix E - WAP (Wireless Access Point) - Wikipedia Learning Notes

> In computer networking, a wireless access point (WAP), or more
>   generally just access point (AP), is ***a networking hardware device
>   that allows other Wi-Fi devices to connect to a wired network.***
>
> ***The AP usually connects to a router (via a wired network) as a standalone device, but it can also be an integral component of the
>   router itself.*** *An AP is differentiated from a hotspot, which is
>   the physical location where Wi-Fi access to a WLAN is available.*
>
> An AP connects directly to a wired local area network, typically
>   Ethernet, and the AP then provides wireless connections using wireless
>   LAN technology, typically Wi-Fi, for other devices to use that wired
>   connection. APs support the connection of multiple wireless devices
>   through their one wired connection.
>
> Wireless access point vs ad hoc network
>
> Some people confuse wireless access points with wireless ad hoc
>   networks. An ad hoc network uses a connection between two or more
>   devices without using a wireless access point; The devices communicate
>   directly when in range. Because setup is easy and does not require an
>   access point, an ad hoc network is used in situations such as a quick
>   data exchange or a multiplayer video game. Due to its peer-to-peer
>   layout, ad hoc Wi-Fi connections are similar to connections available
>   using Bluetooth.
>
> Wireless networking lags wired networking in terms of increasing
>   bandwidth and throughput. As of 2013, high-density 256-QAM (TurboQAM)
>   modulation, 3-antenna wireless devices reach speeds 240 Mbit/s 13m,
>   360Mbit/s at 10m, 380 Mbit/s at 2m, or 20 to 25 Mbit/s at 2m line of
>   sight (IEEE 802.11g), wired hardware of similar cost reaches closer to
>   1000 Mbit/s up to specified distance of 100 m with twisted-pair
>   cabling in optimal conditions (Cat5 or better cabling with Gigabit
>   Ethernet).

*Appendix F - Hotspot (Wi-Fi) - Wikipedia Learning Notes*

> ***A hotspot is a physical location where people may obtain Internet access, typically using Wi-Fi technology, via a wireless local area
>   network (WLAN) using a router connected to an internet service
>   provider.***
>
> Public hotspots may be created by a business for use by customers,
>   such as coffee shops or hotels. *Public hotspots are typically created
>   from wireless access points configured to provide Internet access,
>   controlled to some degree by the venue.* *In its simplest form, venues
>   that have broadband Internet access can create public wireless access
>   by configuring an access point (AP), in conjunction with a router and
>   connecting the AP to the Internet connection. A single wireless router
>   combining these functions may suffice.*
>
> *Private hotspots may be configured on a smartphone or tablet with a mobile network data plan to allow Internet access to other devices via
>   Bluetooth pairing or if both the hotspot device and the device/s
>   accessing it are connected to the same Wi-Fi network.*
>
> *The public can use a laptop or other suitable portable device to access the wireless connection (usually Wi-Fi) provided.* Of the
>   estimated 150 million laptops, 14 million PDAs, and other emerging
>   Wi-Fi devices sold per year for the last few years, most include the
>   Wi-Fi feature.
>
> Public hotspots are often found at airports, bookstores, coffee shops,
>   department stores, fuel stations, hotels, hospitals, libraries, public
>   pay phones, restaurants, RV parks and campgrounds, supermarkets, train
>   stations, and other public places. Additionally, many schools and
>   universities have wireless networks on their campuses.
>
> Free hotspots operate in two ways: Using an open public network is the
>   easiest way to create a free hotspot. All that is needed is a Wi-Fi
>   router. Similarly, when users of private wireless routers turn off
>   their authentication requirements, opening their connection,
>   intentionally or not, they permit piggybacking (sharing) by anyone in
>   range.
>
> Closed public networks use a HotSpot Management System to control
>   access to hotspots. This software runs on the router itself or an
>   external computer allowing operators to authorize only specific users
>   to access the Internet.
>
> A commercial hotspot may feature a captive portal / login screen /
>   splash page that users are redirected to for authentication and/or
>   payment.
>
> Software hotspots
>
> Many Wi-Fi adapters built into or easily added to consumer computers
>   and mobile devices include the functionality to operate as private or
>   mobile hotspots, sometimes referred to as "mi-fi". The use of a
>   private hotspot to enable other personal devices to access the WAN
>   (usually but not always the Internet) is a form of bridging, and known
>   as tethering.
>
> Manufacturers and firmware creators can enable this functionality in
>   Wi-Fi devices on many Wi-Fi devices, depending upon the capabilities
>   of the hardware, and most modern consumer operating systems, including
>   Android, Apple OS X 10.6 and later, Windows mobile, and Linux include
>   features to support this. Additionally wireless chipset manufacturers
>   such as Atheros, Broadcom, Intel and others, may add the capability
>   for certain Wi-Fi NICs, usually used in a client role, to also be used
>   for hotspot purposes. However, some service providers, such as AT&T,
>   Sprint, and T-Mobile charge users for this service or prohibit and
>   disconnect user connections if tethering is detected.
>
> Third-party software vendors offer applications to allow users to
>   operate their own hotspot, whether to access the Internet when on the
>   go, share an existing connection, or extend the range of another
>   hotspot.

*Appendix G - Rpi3 WiFi Station + AP IOT Config API Learning Notes*

> IOT Wifi is very small/***8MB Docker Container*** built for Rpi3. IOT Wifi
>   exposes a simple ***JSON based REST API*** for controlling the wireless
>   network interface. ***This container allows the Raspberry Pi to accept
>   wifi connections as an access point (aka AP) while at the same time
>   connecting to an existing wifi network (station mode).***
>
> ***> IOT Wifi sets up network interfaces, runs hostapd, wpa_supplicant and
>   dnsmasq to run simultaneously, allowing a user (or another service) to
>   connect to the Raspberry Pi via hostapd/dnsmasq and issue commands
>   that configure and connect wpa_supplicant to another AP.*** IOT Wifi then
>   exposes a small web server on the Pi and offers a JSON based REST API
>   to configure Wifi. The IOT Wifi container allows you to build a custom
>   Captive Portal web page or even programmatically connect from another
>   device and use the exposed API to configure the target device.
>
> Using wifi to configure a wifi connection is often a standard
>   requirement for IOT. As Raspberry Pis are becoming a popular choice as
>   an IOT platform, this helps solve the frequent need to manage AP and
>   Station modes.

*Appendix H Rpi3 WiFi Station + AP Setup notes*

> Disable wpa_supplicant on Raspberry Pi
>
> You do not want the default wpa_supplicant (the software that
>   communicates with the wifi driver and connects to Wifi networks,)
>   running and competing with the IOT Wifi container.
>
> - prevent wpa_supplicant from starting on boot $ sudo systemctl mask wpa_supplicant.service
> - rename wpa_supplicant on the host to ensure that it is not # used. sudo mv /sbin/wpa_supplicant /sbin/no_wpa_supplicant
> - kill any running processes named wpa_supplicant $ sudo pkill wpa_supplicant
>
> Install Docker on Raspberry Pi
>
> Ssh into the Pi or use the terminal application from the desktop on
>   the Pi to get a Bash shell.
>
> - Docker install script $ curl -sSL https://get.docker.com | sh
>
> Install Docker
>
> - add pi user to Docker user group $ sudo usermod -aG docker pi
>
> Usermod Docker
>
> Reboot the Pi and test Docker.
>
> $ sudo reboot
>
> After reboot, ensure Docker is installed correctly by running a Hello
>   World Docker container.
>
> - run the Docker Hello World container and remove the container
> - when finished (the --rm flag)

*Appendix I - Wireless Repeater - Wikipedia Learning Notes*

> A wireless ***repeater*** (also called wireless ***range extender***) takes an
>   existing signal from a wireless router or wireless access point and
>   rebroadcasts it to create a second network. When two or more hosts
>   have to be connected with one another over the IEEE 802.11 protocol
>   and the distance is too long for a direct connection to be
>   established, a wireless repeater is used to bridge the gap. It can be
>   a specialized stand alone computer networking device. Also, some
>   wireless network interface controllers (WNIC)s optionally support
>   operating in such a mode. Those outside of the primary network will be
>   able to connect through the new "repeated" network. However, as far as
>   the original router or access point is concerned, only the repeater
>   MAC is connected, making it necessary to enable safety features on the
>   wireless repeater. Wireless repeaters are commonly used to improve
>   signal range and strength within homes and small offices.
>
> Uses - area has no wireless hotspot, area with much interference,
>   computer between access point too great
>
> ***Some wireless range extending devices connect via a USB port. These
>   USB adapters add Wi-Fi capability to desktop PCs and other devices
>   that have standard USB ports. USB supports not only the data transfers
>   required for networking, but it also supplies a power source so that
>   these adapters do not require electrical plugs.***

*Appendix J - Wireless Bridge - Wikipedia Learning Notes*

> A network bridge is a computer networking device that creates a single
>   aggregate network from multiple communication networks or network
>   segments. This function is called ***network bridging***. Bridging is
>   ***distinct from routing. Routing allows multiple networks to communicate
>   independently and yet remain separate, whereas bridging connects two
>   separate networks as if they were a single network***.
>
> In the OSI model, bridging is performed in the data link layer (layer
>   2).[4](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=36&t=138730&start=25) If one or more segments of the bridged network are wireless,
>   the device is known as a wireless bridge.

*/ to continue, ...*

.END