# The docker repository does not have a release file

Tags: raspbian, pi-3

I'm trying to install Docker on a Raspberry Pi 3.

I followed the [instructions](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/debian/#install-using-the-convenience-script) and ran:

```
curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com -o get-docker.sh
sudo sh get-docker.sh
```

When I do this, I get the following error:

```
# Executing docker install script, commit: 2f4ae48
+ sh -c apt-get update -qq >/dev/null 
E: The repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/raspbian 10 Release' does not have a Release file.
```

I've tried to modify the `docker.list` file located at:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d
```

The file contains `deb [arch=armhf] https://download.docker.com/linux/raspbian 10 stable`, but I understand that this file is downloaded/replaced when I run the previous commands. I also took a look at `/etc/apt/sources.list` but there is just 1 deb and it is related to Raspberry Pi. Nevertheless, commenting it out did not solve anything.

I navigated with my web browser to `https://download.docker.com/linux/raspbian` and I can see there is a directory there called `dists`. I tried replacing:

`https://download.docker.com/linux/raspbian 10 stable`

with:

`https://download.docker.com/linux/raspbian/dists/stretch 10 stable`

but I just the same `no release file` error when I try to run `sh get-docker.sh` again...

Does anyone have any ideas?

## Edit:

I can install Docker using the .deb files but the solution posted on the Docker website is incorrect.

Comment: "stretch 10 stable" -> *stretch* is Raspbian 9, 10 is *buster*.

Comment: A couple of days ago I installed the docker enginee and ran the Hello World demo without any problem. ( https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/99843/no-internet-on-client-device-when-connected-to-raspberry-pi )

Comment: `but the solution posted on the Docker website is incorrect` I suggest you notify the people who put that solution on the Docker pages so that they can correct it...

Comment: If you have solved your problem you should write an answer. This will finish the question and show others that it has a solution.

Answer (score 4):

This appears to be an issue with lack of support for Raspbian 10 (buster) on Docker's site, however you can use [this workaround](https://forums.docker.com/t/release-for-raspberry-pi-4-raspbian-buster/77120/4) for now (worked for me):

```
sudo curl -sL https://get.docker.com | sed 's/9)/10)/' | sh
```

Comment: I would **strongly** consider prefixing the URL with `https://`. Running a script without reading it is one of those cases where you want to at least verify the website's certificate.

Comment: I was still getting the same error message. I had to run `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list` first, then this command.