# How to connect wifi wlan1 and share it by wlan0

Tags: access-point

How to connect wifi wlan1 and share it by wlan0
I would like to use raspberry pi become hostpot wifi. connect wifi by wireless and share it not use ethernet or lan.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access point as WiFi router/repeater, optional with bridge](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/89803/access-point-as-wifi-router-repeater-optional-with-bridge) or [Access point as WiFi router/repeater with additional WiFi-dongle](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/95073/79866):

Comment: why do you need a hotspot that has no connectivity to LAN? ... it seems pointless to connect and then have no access to the intranet or to the internet

Comment: i have wifi from Network service providers but it only for 1 device and i do not want to turn on  laptop or tablet to share it around the clock.///i not strong English  language.