# Using an additional WiFi dongle to create WAP and switch

Tags: pi-3b+, hotspot

I followed the answer to this question:

[Access point as WiFi router/repeater with additional WiFi-dongle](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/95072/access-point-as-wifi-router-repeater-with-additional-wifi-dongle)

To have my 3 B+ act as a WiFi hotspot where wlan1 connects to the internet (WAN) and the pi acts as a router with devices connecting to wlan0 on the LAN side.

That works great but I also want to connect a LAN device to eth0

I think I just need to bridge eth0 and wlan0 but haven’t been able to make it work.

Comment: I will extend the setup you have used, with a bridge with wlan0 and eth0. Just a moment please.

Comment: An dhcp server must run on your AP for wireless clients private network (assume wlan0) and on Ethernet (assume eth0) for wire clients private network. I cannot help you because I'm not familiarized with the default dhcp server but if you use dnsmasq , then I can help you. But the steps are the same : 1) `assign an ip address` to `wlan0 (10.17.1.1/24)` and `eth0 (10.17.0.1/24)` interfaces. 2) `Bind` your dhcp server on this precise addresses and `configure the 'client network' scope` in configuration file. 3) start the DHCP daemon(s ?).

Comment: For dnsmasq I use two instance (yes two dhcp and dns server listening on two different network) for that. I exclude necessary interfaces in dnsmasq.conf for dhcp and dns, bind the interfaces on specific assigned ip addr .... and It's work for me.

Comment: @lngo - that would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

To bridge **eth0** with **wlan0** I will start with the setup you have already done with [Access point as WiFi router/repeater with additional WiFi-dongle](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/95073/79866).

You will get this setup:

```
          (dhcp
        from RPi)        bridge
           ╱    wifi    ┌───────┐
mobile-phone <~.~.~.~.> │(wlan0)│              wifi            wan
                        │    br0│RPi(wlan1) <.~.~.~.~> router <───> INTERNET
      laptop <────────> | (eth0)│╲       ╲
           ╲    wired   └───────┘╱      (dhcp
         (dhcp          192.168.4.1   from router)
       from RPi)
```

From the already done setup first rename `08-wlan0.network`:

```
rpi ~$ sudo -Es
rpi ~# mv /etc/systemd/network/08-wlan0.network /etc/systemd/network/16-br0_up.network
```

and change line `Name=wlan0` into `Name=br0` in `/etc/systemd/network/16-br0_up.network`.

Then add these two files:

```
rpi ~# cat > /etc/systemd/network/02-br0.netdev <<EOF
[NetDev]
Name=br0
Kind=bridge
EOF

rpi ~# cat > /etc/systemd/network/04-br0_add-eth0.network <<EOF
[Match]
Name=eth0
[Network]
Bridge=br0
EOF
```

Now we have to tell *wpa_supplicant* for wlan0 to use a bridge. We do it by modifying its service with:

```
rpi ~# systemctl edit wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service
```

In the empty editor insert these statements, save them and quit the editor:

```
[Service]
ExecStartPre=/sbin/iw dev %i set type __ap
ExecStartPre=/bin/ip link set %i master br0

ExecStart=
ExecStart=/sbin/wpa_supplicant -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-%I.conf -Dnl80211,wext -i%I -bbr0

ExecStopPost=-/bin/ip link set %i nomaster
ExecStopPost=-/sbin/iw dev %i set type managed
```

Reboot.
That's it.

**Update** in respect of a comment:

> The interfaces are still wlan0 and wlan1 but on some boots the onboard is wlan0 and sometimes wlan1.

This is a classical use case for [Predictable Network Interface Names](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/). You should enable it and use the new interface names instead of **wlan0** and **wlan1**. The new names, for example **enp9s0** (wired) or **wlxe894f61b0a92** (wireless), will never change. To enable predictable network interface names you can use `sudo raspi-config` and select `2 Network Options -> N3 Network interface names`. If this doesn't help you can also append `net.ifnames=1` to the line in `/boot/cmdline.txt`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Ingo, we just returned from a long European vacation and it worked perfectly on the airplane and cruise ship. The kids were thrilled to have Plex available!

Now that I'm home, I tried the same steps on a Pi 4 but it doesn't work. It looks like the root of the problem is randomly identifying the on-board and WiFi dongle as wlan0 and wlan1. I tried setting them statically the way you can on Stretch but it didn't work.

Comment: @WilliamMeyer What are the names of the interfaces on RPi 4B? Check with `networkctl`.

Comment: they are still wlan0 and wlan1 but on some boots the onboard is wlan0 and sometimes wlan1.

Comment: @WilliamMeyer I have updated my answer at the end.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I tried your suggestion and still no luck. It's currently using wlan1 as LAN but bridge to internet isn't working. prior to your suggestion I was getting the names wlan0 and wlan1 but which was which was random. I had not seen this new wlan name prior to your suggestion:

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ networkctl
3 wlxe894f61b0a92  wlan               off         unmanaged
4 wlan1            wlan               routable    configured

Comment: After looking at it again this morning I realized wl is Wireless Lan and xe894f61b0a92 is the MAC address of the adapter! I understand what is going on now so I'll take another run at it and see if I can get it to work.

Comment: Unfortunately I was not able to get it to work. The Pi itself is connected to the internet, and I can connect to the Pi via WiFi but something has changed with Buster and devices connected to the Pi AP cannot access the internet.