# How can I create a bridge to eth0 with the following network configuration?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, networking, wifi, systemd-networkd

I followed [this tutorial](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/95073/107468) so I have a network with two wireless interfaces, wlan0 working as a access point and wlan1 working as a client from another router. How can I bridge wlan1 to eth0 without installing any extra software if possible? I'm using raspbian buster.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Bridging **eth0** with **wlan1** seems not to make much sense in this context, is not easy and needs hardware WDS support on the USB/WiFi dongle. Bridging **eth0** with **wlan0** is no problem. Then all devices connected wired and wireless to the access point are on the same subnet (same ip address range) and are connected to the internet. Is it this what you want?

Comment: Yes, I want to connect a device to the eth0 port to give it access to the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking how to bridge **eth0** with the uplink  connection **wlan1**. This is not an easy task because bridging a client connection can only be done with WDS mode and must be supported by the hardware. The built-in device of the Raspberry Pi does not support it. For further information about this issue you can look at [Raspberry Pi WiFi to Ethernet Bridge for a server?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/81518/79866). But you could use the USB/WiFi dongle if it supports WDS.

But according to the clarification in your comment this does not solve your problem. To solve it you have to bridge **eth0** with the access point interface **wlan0**. This is not a problem and can easily be done by following setup [Using an additional WiFi dongle to create WAP and switch](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/100013/79866).