# Second WiFi adapter for the Raspberry Pi 4 B

Tags: wifi, hardware

I need a second WiFi adapter for the Raspberry Pi 4.

For RPi <=2 (without integrated WiFi) and with RPi >= 3 the chipset **BCM43143** was recommended.

Does this still apply for the RPi 4? Can I only expect a reliable performance from WiFi dongles with a BCM43143 chipset, or has the support broadened?

I'm eyeballing a TP-Link Archer T3U AC1300, but I don't want to invest a lot of time of getting it running reliably.

Comment: Why not drop a note to some of the official outlets?  For example The Pi Hut has both small and external antenna versions - I'm sure they would be happy for an order at the moment.

Comment: See <https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/112850/issues-installing-rtl8812bu-wifi-driver-on-raspberry-pi-4-b> if the answers above don't work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are free to purchase any additional USB/WiFi dongle that is compatible to Raspberry Pi. You may have a look at [RPi USB Wi-Fi Adapters](https://elinux.org/RPi_USB_Wi-Fi_Adapters). If you have a compatible adapter then it's no problem to use it for a second WiFi connection or as an access point with a WiFi uplink. How to do it you can look at [Access point as WiFi router/repeater with additional WiFi-dongle](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/95073/79866).

Comment: thank you for the link, I've come across this list already, but it seems quite dated.

Answer (score 1):

Many of the rtl88x2bu adapters are compatible with a Rasbperry Pi using [this driver](https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2bu). This is what many cards use that advertise Linux compatibility (e.g. Amazon search for "linux wifi", especially the 1200Mbps ones). If you're using a Pi with a 64-bit kernel, you'll need to run

```bsh
sed -i 's/ARM_NV_NANO = n/ARM_NV_NANO = y/' Makefile
```

*instead of*

```bsh
sed -i 's/ARM_RPI = n/ARM_RPI = y/' Makefile
```

Here's the complete install commands, assuming Raspbian:

```bsh
# Update all packages per normal
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade

# Install prereqs
# Remove raspberrypi-kernel-headers if you're running Ubuntu or you get package-not-found errors
sudo apt install git build-essential dkms raspberrypi-kernel-headers

# Reboot just in case there were any kernel updates, you can skip if there weren't
sudo reboot

# Pull down the driver source
git clone https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2bu
cd rtl88x2bu/

# Configure for RasPi
sed -i 's/I386_PC = y/I386_PC = n/' Makefile
# Remember, change this if you're using a 64-bit kernel
sed -i 's/ARM_RPI = n/ARM_RPI = y/' Makefile

VER=$(sed -n 's/\PACKAGE_VERSION="\(.*\)"/\1/p' dkms.conf)
sudo rsync -rvhP ./ /usr/src/rtl88x2bu-${VER}
sudo dkms add -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}
sudo dkms build -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER} # Takes ~3-minutes on a 3B+
sudo dkms install -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}
sudo modprobe 88x2bu
```

I've confirmed that [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07F6D7DH8) works on Ubuntu 18.04 64-bit on a Pi 4, and I'm getting pings of <40ms and download speeds of >200Mbps.

Answer (score 1):

We are successfully using a **TP-Link TL-WN722N** (Realtek chipset, i.e. [v2](http://en.techinfodepot.shoutwiki.com/wiki/TP-LINK_TL-WN722N_v2) or [v3](http://en.techinfodepot.shoutwiki.com/wiki/TP-LINK_TL-WN722N_v3)) adapter with a Raspberry Pi Zero W running balenaOS 2.54. It was completely plug-and-play; no drivers necessary.