# Issues installing RTL8812BU WIFI driver on Raspberry Pi 4 B

Tags: wifi, pi-4, driver, usb3

Recently, I bought a USB3 WiFi adapter with the RTL8812BU chip (Supports Linux).
I have spent 5 hours so far trying to install the Linux driver for the chip on my **Raspberry Pi 4**.
Apparently, I am not able to do this on my own so I hope that you guys can help me.

Here is what I have done so far:

**Install build tools:**

```
sudo apt install build-essential bc git wget libssl-dev bison flex dkms
```

**Get kernel source code**

```
cd /usr/src
sudo git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux.git
sudo ln -s linux $(uname -r)
sudo ln -s /usr/src/linux /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build
```

**Prepare linux build headers**

```
cd linux
sudo wget -O Module.symvers https://raw.githubusercontent.com/raspberrypi/firmware/master/extra/Module7l.symvers
KERNEL=kernel7l
sudo make bcm2711_defconfig
sudo make prepare
sudo make modules_prepare
```

**Install Driver**

```
sudo git clone https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2bu.git
cd rtl88x2bu
VER=$(sed -n 's/\PACKAGE_VERSION="\(.*\)"/\1/p' dkms.conf)
sudo rsync -rvhP ./ /usr/src/rtl88x2bu-${VER}
sudo dkms add -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}
sudo nano Makefile
```

Change 2 lines to this:

```
CONFIG_PLATFORM_I386_PC = n  
CONFIG_PLATFORM_ARM_RPI = y
```

```
sudo ARCH=arm dkms build -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}                             
sudo dkms install -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}
sudo modprobe 88x2bu
```

**The problem**
When I run the last command `sudo modprobe 88x2bu` I get this error message:

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert '88x2bu': Exec format error
```

So I guess that the `Makefile` setting `CONFIG_PLATFORM_ARM_RPI` is not compatible with Raspberry Pi 4 but only earlier models.

**Can I modify the `Makefile` and add a new platform type that allows the driver to be built for Raspberry Pi 4? Or how do I approach this issue?**

I have seen other `RealTek` drivers that supports Raspberry Pi 4 through a variable in the `Makefile` named `CONFIG_PLATFORM_ARM64_RPI`. I am a programmer myself (not a Linux programmer though) but I simply don't know what I want the `Makefile` code to do when `CONFIG_PLATFORM_ARM64_RPI` is set to y.

Example of a `RealTek` driver that supports Raspberry Pi 4 (These does not work with my WIFI adaptor however so just fyi):
https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au

**Official driver attempt**
I also have the official drivers available to me from this link:
https://archive.org/details/realtekdrivers_rtl8811_rtl8812

But in the ./driver folder after unpacking the tar file, I look in the Makefile and here i dont find any RPI options under CONFIGURATION_PLATFORM_*

I tried to add a new line

```
CONFIG_PLATFORM_ARM64_RPI = y
```

and ran the `install.sh` script but it fails (of course because the `Makefile` does not handle the new `CONFIG_PLATFORM_ARM64_RPI` line).

and `dmesg` shows this error message:
[  542.113848] 88x2bu: disagrees about version of symbol module_layout

**More information**
Here is some more information about my setup.

Result of `uname -smr`:
Linux 4.19.115-v7l+ armv7l

I hope that you can help me with tips on how to proceed with this issue!
Hopefully the answer will also help other people in the future.

**EDIT 2020-05-31:**
I have also tried to use

```
    sudo make modules
```

to build `Module.symvers` instead of getting it with `wget`.
That did not help.

And I tried to upgrade my kernel to 5.4.42-v7l+ with

```
sudo rpi-update
sudo wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/notro/rpi-source/master/rpi-source -O /usr/local/bin/rpi-source && sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/rpi-source && /usr/local/bin/rpi-source -q --tag-update
sudo rpi-source
```

However, after upgrading it fails in an earlier step so I have rolled back the upgrade.

Comment: The Pi4 has built in WiFi hardware.

Comment: Yes, it does. But I have some issues with that. First, I am using an aluminium case which lowers the internal WiFi signal. Second I am using USB3 devices and USB3 and the internal 2.4Ghz WiFi interferes with each other so the internal WiFi does not work when a USB3 device is plugged in. So I bought a more powerful USB3 WiFi adapter to overcome those challenges. I just need to make it work on Pi4 :-) And before you suggest that I use 5Ghz WiFi, I just want to mention that it is not an option either. Range is way too short on that for my needs.

Comment: In my case, I got a "target not found" for arch/arm/kernel/ on my Manjaro ARM version. I set ARCH=arm64 in the Makefile to solve the issue. Remember to update the Makefile in /usr/src/rtl88x2bu-${VER} with rsync.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally I had a breakthrough!

Instead of using `modprobe` and `dkms`, it was enough to follow these steps:

```
sudo git clone https://github.com/EntropicEffect/rtl8822bu.git 
cd rtl8822bu
sudo nano Makefile
```

Update lines 100 and 101 to this and save the file:

```
CONFIG_PLATFORM_I386_PC = n  
CONFIG_PLATFORM_ARM_RPI = y
```

```
sudo apt-get install raspberrypi-kernel-headers
sudo make
sudo make install
sudo reboot
```

After reboot I did `iwconfig` and now I see two wireless USB adapters.
And a quick speed test with `speedtest-cli` makes me very happy:

```
Ping: 7.414 ms
Download: 133.61 Mbit/s
Upload: 153.04 Mbit/s
```

Comment: Even though EntropicEffect/rtl8822bu is no longer maintained, these instructions worked like a charm! 3x better WiFi speeds with TP-Link T4U v3 compared to built-in RPi4 WiFi.

Comment: Didn't work for me on RPi CM4 using 64-bit OS until I ran as `ARCH=arm64 make && make install`

Comment: The EntropicEffect/rtl8822bu no longer complies in the September 2022 release of the Pi OS. Try https://github.com/drygdryg/rtl8188eus.git

Comment: on Raspberry Pi 4b using bookworm I get this error: `fatal error: net/ipx.h: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get install dkms
git clone https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2bu.git
cd rtl88x2bu
VER=$(sed -n 's/\PACKAGE_VERSION="\(.*\)"/\1/p' dkms.conf)
sudo rsync -rvhP ./ /usr/src/rtl88x2bu-${VER}
sudo dkms add -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}
sudo dkms build -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}
sudo dkms install -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}
sudo modprobe 88x2bu
```

Remember to reboot.
Source: [AC1300 TP-link adapter doesn't work](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=306627)

My speed: 140 Mb/s U:78Mb/s at this AC1300 Wi-Fi

My speed at cable Cu, classic wired UTP connector> D:288mb/s  U: 165Mb/s

Country: Romania

SSD 512 WD, +12 GB RAM DDR3, microprocesor old: 2x3000 MHz

Comment: I was able to install rtl88x2bu driver on a Raspberry Pi 1B and It's working! It wouldn't compile because only 256MB RAM but after changing my swap to 2G I was able to compile (it took 2h aprox). Thank you!

Comment: These instructions are out of date. I followed the instructions here and it worked: https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2bu

Comment: The links to the images are dead. This is why the images should be uploaded to the stack exchange server and not be links to external sites.