# Second wifi (dongle) only as local network

Tags: wifi, pi-3b+

I'm running Raspberry Pi (3B+) 9 (stretch) Wlan0 connected to WAN with network info stored in wpa_supplicant.conf.

I recently purchased an Wifi dongle in order to create a wireless access point from which an Arduino can connect and transmit data (temperature readings) in to the raspberry with a lightweight webserver. This secondary network does not need to be bridged with wlan0 (WAN), since its purpose is to only retrieve data from arduino.

I'm able to find several questions which addresses the issue of using the second wlan1 as a repeater or bridge to wlan0, but not as stand alone local network. Preferably i also want the network SSID to be hidden.

Any good solutions ?

Comment: Just follow [this tutorial](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md) but leave out the routing and masquerade part. If you want to use `systemd-networkd` you could also follow [this tutorial](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/88234/92303).

Comment: The first tutorial solved my problem. Thanks Jake

Comment: Please make your comments an answer and accept it after two days. Only accepting an answer will finish your question and it will not pop up again and again for years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a simple setup you can use an [Access point as WiFi router/repeater with additional WiFi-dongle](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/95073/79866). It uses **systemd-networkd** so you do not need any additional software. The setup is called a router/repeater but it is no problem to disable routing. In file `/etc/systemd/network/08-wlan0.network` there is an option `IPForward=yes`. Simply just comment it and you do not have a WiFi router/repeater anymore, just an access point and a client connection to your internet router.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I had some issues using this setup and ended up using Jake's reply in OP.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the normal dhcpcd setup for wlan0.

See [How to set up networking/WiFi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

The Foundation [Access Point](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md) tutorial should explain how to configure the second interface.

```
interface wlan1
    static ip_address=192.168.4.1/24
    nohook wpa_supplicant
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Jake's reply in question post solved my problem.