# Is it possible to make access raspberry pi 3b+ access point from wifi without ethernet and other external devices?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3b+

Is it possible to create access point from Raspberry Pi 3B+, without ethernet? I'd like to create access point like for example android hotspot, were you can start hotspot but you still can use internet on device as well. 
Do you have any idea how can I make it?

Comment: Yes  I do this following the Foundation tutorial

Comment: what makes you believe that ethernet may be required for correct operation of WiFi?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access point as WiFi router/repeater, optional with bridge](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/89803/access-point-as-wifi-router-repeater-optional-with-bridge). You can also use [Access point as WiFi router/repeater with additional WiFi-dongle](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/95072/79866).

Answer (score 0):

I think no, but I am not 100% sure. I think it is not possible because at any one time either you can join a hotspot or create one, but you can't receive and send. You can test it with an external Wi-Fi adapter so one can use as receiver and second one as transmitter or AP, as a Wi-Fi repeater does.

Comment: It is possible. Please note the duplicate flagging comment on the question.