# systemd-networkd: Bond Ethernet and Wifi (USB Dongle), AP with Raspi 3b+ on board Wifi

Tags: pi-3b+, access-point, raspbian-buster, systemd-networkd

Raspbian Buster Lite, Raspi 3b+

I want to bond ethernet (eth0) and a USB wifi dongle (wlan1) for network/internet access. This part I've managed with success, dynamic failover works perfectly.

The problem is when I create an AP assigned to the Raspi's built-in wifi (wlan0). 
With the USB wifi dongle (wlan1) plugged in, I always lose AP access- wlan0 is shown as "down".

**systemd-networkd with Dynamic Failover: network interfaces eth0 (Ethernet), wlan1 (USB Wifi Dongle)**

```
#Create Systemd Network

-Es

cat >/etc/resolvconf.conf <<EOF
# Set to NO to disable resolvconf from running any subscribers. Defaults to YES.
resolvconf=NO
EOF

systemctl mask networking.service

mv /etc/network/interfaces /etc/network/interfaces~

systemctl mask dhcpcd.service

systemctl enable systemd-networkd.service

systemctl enable systemd-resolved.service

ln -sf /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf

cat >/etc/systemd/network/04-eth.network <<EOF
[Match]
Name=eth0
[Network]
# to use static IP (with your settings) toggle commenting the next 8 lines.
#Address=192.168.50.60/24
#DNS=84.200.69.80 1.1.1.1
#[Route]
#Gateway=192.168.50.1
#Metric=10
DHCP=yes
[DHCP]
RouteMetric=10
EOF

-Es

cat >/etc/systemd/network/08-wifi.network <<EOF
[Match]
Name=wlan1
[Network]
# to use static IP (with your settings) toggle commenting the next 8 lines.
#Address=192.168.50.61/24
#DNS=84.200.69.80 1.1.1.1
#[Route]
#Gateway=192.168.50.1
#Metric=20
DHCP=yes
[DHCP]
RouteMetric=20
EOF

cat >/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan1.conf <<EOF
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=US

network={
    ssid="My_Wifi"
    psk="My_Password"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
EOF

chmod 600 /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan1.conf

systemctl disable wpa_supplicant.service

systemctl enable wpa_supplicant@wlan1.service
```

**Bond Network Interfaces eth0 and wlan1**

```
############# Bond eth0 and wlan1 ###############

-Es

mv /etc/systemd/network/04-eth.network /etc/systemd/network/04-eth.network~

mv /etc/systemd/network/08-wifi.network /etc/systemd/network/08-wifi.network~

cat >/etc/systemd/network/02-bond0.netdev <<EOF
[NetDev]
# status: cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0
Name=bond0
Kind=bond
[Bond]
Mode=active-backup
# primary slave is defined in *eth.network
MIIMonitorSec=500ms
UpDelaySec=1000ms
DownDelaySec=1000ms
MinLinks=1
EOF

cat >/etc/systemd/network/12-bond0-add-eth.network <<EOF
[Match]
Name=eth0
[Network]
Bond=bond0
PrimarySlave=yes
EOF

cat >/etc/systemd/network/16-bond0-add-wifi.network <<EOF
[Match]
Name=wlan1
[Network]
Bond=bond0
EOF

cat >/etc/systemd/network/20-bond0-up.network <<EOF
[Match]
Name=bond0
[Network]
# to use static IP (with your settings) toggle commenting the next 4 lines.
DHCP=yes
IPForward=yes
#Address=192.168.50.60/24
#Gateway=192.168.50.1
#DNS=84.200.69.80 1.1.1.1
EOF
```

**Creating Access Point, wlan0 (Raspi built-in wifi)**

```
############# Create AP Access Point wlan0 ###############

cat > /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf <<EOF
country=US
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="My_AP"
    mode=2
    frequency=2437
    #key_mgmt=NONE   # uncomment this for an open hotspot
    # delete next 3 lines if key_mgmt=NONE
    ## Enabling key_mgmt prevents login and returns incorrect password
    #key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    proto=RSN WPA
    psk="My_AP_Pass"
}
EOF

chmod 600 /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf

systemctl enable wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service

cat > /etc/systemd/network/08-wlan0.network <<EOF
[Match]
Name=wlan0
[Network]
Address=192.168.4.1/24
DHCPServer=yes
[DHCPServer]
DNS=84.200.69.80 1.1.1.1
EOF

systemctl edit wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service

[Service]
ExecStartPre=/sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o bond0 -j MASQUERADE
ExecStopPost=-/sbin/iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o bond0 -j MASQUERADE
```

**Reference**

[Setting up a Raspberry Pi as an access point - the easy way](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/88214/setting-up-a-raspberry-pi-as-an-access-point-the-easy-way)

[How to migrate from networking to systemd-networkd with dynamic failover](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/78787/howto-migrate-from-networking-to-systemd-networkd-with-dynamic-failover)

**Additional Information**

I have tried using three different Wifi USB dongles:

RTL8811AU Chipset

RTL8188EUS Chipset

RTL8188EU Chipset

All of the above work and it does not seem to be a particular Wifi dongle that knocks out the Raspi's built-in Wifi.

This behavior is consistent with Raspbian Stretch Lite and Raspbian Buster Lite, Raspi 3b+ and Raspi 4.

I have tested this setup on Armbian Stretch and Armbian Buster (OPi hardware) and behavior is identical to Raspbian setup.

Using predictable network interface naming. I have not tried to assign by MAC Address and would prefer not to in the event I would like to clone the drive and use another Raspi and/or Wifi dongle.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed feedback. I'm just checking it. At a first glance I also run into problems starting my second wifi dongle on RPi 4B, no  matter if bonding or not. Haven't tested it before. Will come back.

Comment: Thank you! I updated my post to include Wifi dongle chipsets and specific setups I've used for testing.

Comment: Sorry, but I had some problems with my test environment. There was a shortcut on the USB to TTL adapter for the debug console that confused the RasPi and the monitoring laptop. Fortunately the TTL shortcut doesn't fried my RasPi but what I commented before has another reason. Look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have a conflict running the USB/WiFi dongle together with the built-in WiFi device. Starting with a fresh flashed Raspbian Buster Lite image first I verified on my Raspberry Pi 4B that it is working properly without bonding using this setup [Access point as WiFi router/repeater with additional WiFi-dongle](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/95073/79866).

It works.

Then I flashed the image again and exactly used the setup you have given in your question. And what should I say?

It also works.

Here are some output for comparison:

```
rpi ~$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master bond0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 9a:9f:4d:64:fa:0d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 9a:9f:4d:64:fa:0d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.50.205/24 brd 192.168.50.255 scope global dynamic bond0
       valid_lft 2108sec preferred_lft 2108sec
    inet6 fe80::989f:4dff:fe64:fa0d/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:a6:32:01:db:ed brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.4.1/24 brd 192.168.4.255 scope global wlan0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::dea6:32ff:fe01:dbed/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: wlan1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master bond0 state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 9a:9f:4d:64:fa:0d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

```
rpi ~$ iw dev
phy#1
    Interface wlan1
        ifindex 5
        wdev 0x100000001
        addr 9a:9f:4d:64:fa:0d
        ssid TestNet
        type managed
        channel 6 (2437 MHz), width: 20 MHz, center1: 2437 MHz
        txpower 30.00 dBm
phy#0
    Unnamed/non-netdev interface
        wdev 0x2
        addr aa:66:d1:aa:f6:19
        type P2P-device
        txpower 31.00 dBm
    Interface wlan0
        ifindex 4
        wdev 0x1
        addr dc:a6:32:01:db:ed
        ssid RPiNet
        type AP
        channel 6 (2437 MHz), width: 20 MHz, center1: 2437 MHz
        txpower 31.00 dBm
```

```
rpi ~$ cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0
Ethernet Channel Bonding Driver: v3.7.1 (April 27, 2011)

Bonding Mode: fault-tolerance (active-backup)
Primary Slave: eth0 (primary_reselect always)
Currently Active Slave: eth0
MII Status: up
MII Polling Interval (ms): 500
Up Delay (ms): 1000
Down Delay (ms): 1000

Slave Interface: eth0
MII Status: up
Speed: 1000 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: dc:a6:32:01:db:ec
Slave queue ID: 0

Slave Interface: wlan1
MII Status: up
Speed: Unknown
Duplex: Unknown
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: 00:0e:00:20:08:13
Slave queue ID: 0
```

If I unplug the wired cable then my smartphone connected to the access point continued to browse the internet, means dynamic failover also works.

Comment: Something is not right with my bond config. Can you post your bond0 configuration?

Comment: @Evos I don't know what I should post about the the **bond0** configuration. Look at your question and you will find the setup. As already said I followed it line by line except configuring wpa_supplicant with `country=DE` and using ssid and psk from my location. Maybe there is a problem with your wireless connection? Does **wlan0** and **wlan1** work without bonding as shown in the link at my answer?

Comment: It does not appear to be a problem with USB/Wifi, I test the connection through each section of the process. There are differences between our output: Bond mode for me returns round-robin and does not show wlan1 as a slave interface. I have to think that there must be a difference in our configurations and if not, why the output isn't similar.

Comment: Bond mode is set in `/etc/systemd/network/02-bond0.netdev` with `Mode=active-backup`. Setting this was buggy with systemd 232 comming with Raspbian Stretch. With it you have to load the bonding module with parameter direct. How to do it look at https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/revisions/78788/15 and search for `/etc/modprobe.d/bonding.conf`. But this should not be an issue because we both are using Raspbian Buster with systemd 241 that has fixed the bugs as you can see with my setup.