# Raspberry Wlan Reapter without Internal Wifi - I want to use USB/Dongle ( wlan1 ) POSSIBLE?

Tags: wifi

just a short scenario i want to use Raspbeery as a Wlan Repeater with a 
USB/Dongle Wlan Adapter because the internal has less Range.

Is there any chance to get this scenario to work?
if so any help is welcome
thanks in advance

Robert

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access point as WiFi router/repeater with additional WiFi-dongle](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/95072/access-point-as-wifi-router-repeater-with-additional-wifi-dongle)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use this setup using Raspberry Pi as [Access point as WiFi router/repeater, optional with bridge](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/89804/79866). Just search and replace all occurrence of **wlan0** with **wlan1** in that setup and it should do. Maybe you have also to correct the context on some places but that can only be formal changes provided the USB/WiFi dongle has at least the same hardware options than the built-in WiFi device. Otherwise the setup should be a good template to adapt it to your dongle anyway. Give me a comment to this answer if there are some problems.