# Using a Compute Module 3+ as both an AP and regular WiFi

Tags: networking, access-point

I am using [this](https://github.com/lukicdarkoo/rpi-wifi) github project to create an access point on my Pi, in order to allow setup of WiFi information via a phone app.

I have successfully run the setup on a Pi 4 using Buster, and used the same sd card in a Pi 3+ after changing the MAC address in /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules.

However, due to a change in what I need to have this work on, I have to get it working on a Compute Module3+ that is attached to a Compute Module IO Board V3.0. Since it doesn't have built in networking capabilities, I am also using a CanaKit WiFi adapter.

When I boot it up with the SD card, I get errors in the networking service, specifically:

```
Could not set interface wlan0 flags (UP): Device or resource busy
WEXT: Could not set interface 'wlan0' UP
wlan0: Failed to initialize driver interface
Failed to start Raise network interfaces
```

ifconfig only shows ap0 as being up, and I can connect to it via my phone and communicate via my App, but it is unable to connect to the internet afterwords.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot see much from the link you have referenced. From your description I assume you want to have an access point together with a WiFi client connection as uplink to another hotspot. I don't know anything about the Compute Module but because you wrote it may be software compatible to RPi 3B+ and 4B you can have a look at solutions for them.

The error message you described is well known. It is due to the problem that the initialization of the interfaces **wlan0** and **ap0** and starting helper programs like `wpa_supplicant` and `hostapd` have to follow a strict order. How to manage it you can look at [Access point as WiFi router/repeater, optional with bridge](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/89804/79866).

Using an additional USB/WiFi dongle would simplify the setup a lot. Then you will have two completely independent interfaces **wlan0** and **wlan1** and you don`t run into the error you have described. How to use this you can look at [Access point as WiFi router/repeater with additional WiFi-dongle](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/95073/79866).