# Creating an AP with hostapd and a Wi-Fi backend

Tags: wifi, pi-3b+, raspbian-buster, hostapd

**The problem:**  I am trying to create an AP on a Raspberry Pi 3B (want to later try on a Zero W, too) running buster.  I also want to have Internet connectivity to the Pi using my Wi-Fi.  I have studied several tutorials such as:

https://thepi.io/how-to-use-your-raspberry-pi-as-a-wireless-access-point/

and others and successfully implemented a solution using eth0.  However, what I want is that instead of eth0 the Pi should use wlan1.  To this end I looked up various ways of doing using dual Wi-Fi:

https://www.processthings.com/post/66023171876/how-to-connect-your-raspberry-pi-to-two-wi-fi
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=49283

I even followed this: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=191453

but I am unable to achieve my objective. Here’s what my files look like

**/etc/dhcpcd.conf**

```
interface wlan0
static ip_address=192.168.1.11/24
denyinterfaces eth0
denyinterfaces wlan0
```

**/etc/dnsmasq.conf**

```
interface=wlan0
  dhcp-range=192.168.1.21,192.168.1.30,255.255.255.0,24h
```

**/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf**

```
interface=wlan0
bridge=br0
hw_mode=g
channel=7
wmm_enabled=0
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
ssid=Hello123
wpa_passphrase=asdasdasd
```

**/etc/default/hostapd**

```
DAEMON_CONF="/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf"
```

**/etc/network/interfaces**

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
#iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto wlan1
iface wlan1 inet dhcp
wpa-ssid Hello123
wpa-psk asdasdasd
```

I cannot connect to the net (cannot browse or ping) and ifconfig doesn’t show wlan1 at all.

So, what am I doing wrong? And is it even possible for wlan0 and wlan1 to coexist in this fashion? All the examples using hostapd only show eth0 bridges. In fact, I am OK even if the bridging doesn't happen - I just need the ability to connect to the Pi through AP mode and the Pi should be able to contact a website for data.

Answer (score 3):

It is unclear what you really want:

> I just need the ability to connect to the Pi through AP mode and the Pi should be able to contact a website for data

But you are talking about **wlan1** that is usually provided by an additional USB/WiFi dongle. You do not need it for what you have written. With a Raspberry Pi 3B+ you can just use the built-in WiFi with interface **wlan0** and its wired port with interface **eth0**. With **wlan0** you create the access point and with a wired connection on **eth0** you have the uplink to your internet router. How to configure it you can look at

[Setting up a Raspberry Pi as an access point - the easy way](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/88234/79866).

You may use section **"♦ Setting up an access point and with eth0, with NAT (recommended)"**. If you like to have bridge then look at section "**♦ Setting up an access point with a bridge**".

If you want to have a wireless uplink instead of the wired connection you can look at [Access point as WiFi router/repeater, optional with bridge](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/89804/79866) or if you want to use an additional USB/WiFi dongle then you can use an [Access point as WiFi router/repeater with additional WiFi-dongle](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/95073/79866).

Answer (score 0):

Try running the commands as follows:

```
rfkill list wlan
rfkill unblock wlan
echo "Check that wifi is unblocked."
rfkill list wlan
```

Just use the command

```
man rfkill
```

for an explanation.

Raspbian now uses rfkill to disable wifi if there is no valid country code in /etc/wpa-supplicant/wpa-supplicant.conf.  This seems to be a relatively new addition which is why scripts that used to work no longer do.

Dazz

Comment: What does this do?  Can you  provide an expanation?