# RPI2 with two WiFis works ok for single requests, browsing is impossible

Tags: networking, wifi, pi-2

I want like to create a simple WiFi booster with Raspberry PI. So I have RPI2 with two dongles: Ralink (rt2800usb) and Edimax (rtl8812au).

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 148f:5370 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5370 Wireless Adapter
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 7392:a812 Edimax Technology Co., Ltd
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMSC9512/9514 Fast Ethernet Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMC9514 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ readlink /sys/class/net/wlan0/device/driver
../../../../../../../../bus/usb/drivers/rtl8812au
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ readlink /sys/class/net/wlan1/device/driver
../../../../../../../../bus/usb/drivers/rt2800usb

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo cat /etc/network/interfaces.d/wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
    wpa-ssid VMXXX
    wpa-psk 33XXX
    wireless-power off

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo cat /etc/network/interfaces.d/wlan1
allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet static
    metric 100
    address 192.168.5.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.5.0
    wireless-power off

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo cat /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
country_code=GB
interface=wlan1
ssid=Raspberry
hw_mode=g
channel=8
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wmm_enabled=1
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=12XXXXXXXX
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ iwconfig
eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan1     IEEE 802.11  Mode:Master  Tx-Power=20 dBm
          Retry short  long limit:2   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11AC  ESSID:"VM5141922-5G"  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.22 GHz  Access Point: 40:0D:10:97:FF:0F
          Bit Rate:434 Mb/s   Sensitivity:0/0
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=87/100  Signal level=49/100  Noise level=0/100
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

`dnsmasq` and `dhcpcd` are configured to share internet from wlan0 to wlan1.

It all seems to work well. From the notebook connected to this access point:

```
C:\Users\Alex> tracert google.com

Tracing route to google.com [216.58.210.238]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     3 ms     2 ms     7 ms  192.168.5.1 <- this is Raspberry PI
  2    64 ms     7 ms     7 ms  192.168.0.1 <- this is home router
  3    18 ms    13 ms    16 ms  ...
```

Ping is nice:

```
Reply from 192.168.5.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.5.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.5.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.5.1: bytes=32 time=5ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.5.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.5.1: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=64
```

However when I start browsing anything more complicated than a simple Web-page it quickly becomes unreliable: delays up to 3 seconds and packet drops.

```
Reply from 192.168.5.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.5.1: bytes=32 time=296ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.5.1: bytes=32 time=77ms TTL=64
Request timed out.
Reply from 192.168.5.1: bytes=32 time=442ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.5.1: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.5.1: bytes=32 time=377ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.5.1: bytes=32 time=526ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.5.1: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.5.1: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.5.1: bytes=32 time=678ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.5.1: bytes=32 time=384ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.5.1: bytes=32 time=19ms TTL=64
```

I've searched for solution on this forum and others and it seems that power could be an issue. Is there successful configuration with two dongles and any RPI version that works well under load?

Comment: Have you thought about using a powered hub?

Comment: What operating system do you use? You can try an [Access point as WiFi router/repeater with additional WiFi-dongle](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/95073/79866)

Comment: @Andyroo thanks, perhaps I should try it.

Comment: @Ingo it is latest Raspbian. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Do you mean the latest OS or the latest **Raspbian**?. The latest OS is **Raspberry Pi OS**. You should exactly name the version.